# Audio Injector input to Bluetooth Output

Tags: pi-3, audio, puredata

What I am trying to do is have the audio come into the Raspberry Pi via the Audio Injector "Stereo" and then pass through the Pi and output the audio to Bluetooth speakers.  I have successfully installed the Audio Injector "Stereo", I think.  I got the audio out from the "Stereo" working.  I successfully connected to my Bluetooth speakers and got audio out to the speakers working.  My problem is the audio in. I tried using Audacity to record the input sound from the "Stereo" board, but it seemed like it didn't record any audio.

So does anyone know how to get audio in via the stereo component inputs to the Audio Injector and then output the sound to Bluetooth speakers?

I tried "Pure Data," but the bluetooth speaker does not show up as an option for output.  I followed the steps from Scott Lumsden ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0stTmBmTyHk) to get the Audio Injector and Pure Data working, but he doesn't account for Bluetooth speakers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-Mike